# Why was the original Q&A apology about Monica Cellio deleted?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

After reading on the subject, in one of the many, many Q&As and comments on it, I noticed the original link is now a 404 page (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology).

**What gives?**

I understand it experienced a record-level downvote; yet at the same time, it would certainly be interesting from a community history standpoint, especially as passions wane as it becomes bygones.

Perhaps disable answers, edits, and lock it?

Comment: I see this is a duplicate of another question, which, for some reason, did not show up even after researching it -- although I was convinced someone had to have asked it... It turns out, someone had, but I didn't find it.

Comment: You probably didn't find it because it didn't use the word "original". Anyway, I'm upvoting this since I think that that's a useful thing to search for, and would like to keep this as a signpost.